# cloundconvert api v2 in php return The tasks field is required

Tags: php, api, cloudconvert

We are trying to update to cloudconvert api v2 as the v1 is not working anymore from january 2022.

I have been following their code and even used their online builder, which seems to work, but when testing on the server I get the following error:

[image]

This is how the code look which, is identical to what I got from them, except I replaced with the variables I need on the server instead of hardcoding it.

```
$job = (new Job())
                        ->addTask(
                            (new Task('import/raw', 'import-my-file'))
                                ->set('file', file_get_contents($f->file_current))
                                ->set('filename', $pinfo_basename)
                        )
                        ->addTask(
                            (new Task('convert', 'task-1'))
                                ->set('input_format', $f->file_current_type)
                                ->set('output_format', $f->file_convert_type)
                                ->set('engine', 'poppler')
                                ->set('input', ['import-my-file'])
                                ->set('width', 1920)
                                ->set('quality', 100)
                        )
                        ->addTask(
                            (new Task('export/s3', 'export-1'))
                                ->set('input', ["task-1"])
                                ->set('bucket', $this->amazon_s3_media[$mode]["bucket"])
                                ->set('region', $this->amazon_s3_media[$mode]["region"])
                                ->set('access_key_id', $this->amazon_s3_media[$mode]["access"])
                                ->set('secret_access_key', $this->amazon_s3_media[$mode]["secret"])
                                ->set('acl', 'private')
                                ->set('key_prefix', $f->folder_name)
                        );
                        $cloudconvert->jobs()->create($job);
```

I am wondering what I am doing differently to get that error and wondered if anyone is able to help me with it.

Comment: So I found out when I take the info I get from file_get_contents($f->file_current) and put into file it does not work, but if I print it to the screen and then put that hardcoded into file it works, not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
For it to not throw the error, I had to change my file_get_contens a bit, I did this by doing the following:

$file = rtrim(file_get_contents($f->file_current, FILE_TEXT));
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($file, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));

and then put $file in to ->set('file', $file) instead of ->set('file', file_get_contents($f->file_current))

So converting it from one encoding to another seemed to fix it.